# Holdup/Delay for a while after selecting an image in image library

Tags: android

What's my steps
1. in the Activity, intent method is used to show an image library
2. then select an image from image library
3. and then automatically call onActivityResult method in the Activity
4. execute a 5 seconds UI task in onActivityResult

My issue is:
There's an nearly 5 seconds' holdup/pause after finishing selecting an image from image library before the image library disappear.

My question:
it's a bad user experience to have such kind of holdup. Is there any way to close image library first then executing onActivityResult?

Thanks

Comment: why dont you post your code then it would be easy to analyse ..

Comment: Do you like waiting 5 seconds for something to process?  I bet you don't, and I don't either.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there are some methods to solve your problem.

1.Use a handler and do your time-consuming job in post delay, set the delay to 1000ms. Then you can see the gallery close first.

2.Use the following code to make a gallery selection fragment

```
       String[] projection = new String[] { MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID, MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME, MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_ID, "COUNT(*) AS " + CALLS_COUNT };
        String selection = "1=1) GROUP BY (" + MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_ID;

        cursor = getContext().getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, null, null);
```

then you can pop the fragment first.

3.**Actually**, you should do the time-consuming job in a thread, NEVER block the UI-thread!